# Monero Wallet and Monerod Network Connection Issue on Tails

Tags: monero-wallet-gui, monerod, linux

I am running Tails on a Live USB and am attempting to run a local node with the blockchain being stored onto an SSD.

I have updated IP tables:

```
sudo iptables -I OUTPUT 2 -p tcp -d 127.0.0.1 -m tcp --dport 18081 -j ACCEPT
```

and am running:

```
#!/bin/bash
export DNS_PUBLIC=tcp
gnome-terminal -- bash -c "torsocks \"$PWD/monerod\" --no-igd --prune-blockchain --p2p-bind-ip 127.0.0.1 --rpc-bind-ip 127.0.0.1 --rpc-bind-port 17600 --data-dir /mnt/evo/.bitmonero ;read -p \"Press enter to close\""
```

The following error is constantly printed in the terminal:

```
1634484874 PERROR torsocks[14193]: socks5 libc connect: Connection refused (in socks5_connect() at socks5.c:202)
1634484875 PERROR torsocks[14193]: socks5 libc connect: Connection refused (in socks5_connect() at socks5.c:202)
1634484876 PERROR torsocks[14193]: socks5 libc connect: Connection refused (in socks5_connect() at socks5.c:202)
1634484877 PERROR torsocks[14193]: socks5 libc connect: Connection refused (in socks5_connect() at socks5.c:202)
1634484878 PERROR torsocks[14193]: socks5 libc connect: Connection refused (in socks5_connect() at socks5.c:202)
1634484879 PERROR torsocks[14193]: socks5 libc connect: Connection refused (in socks5_connect() at socks5.c:202)
1634484880 PERROR torsocks[14193]: socks5 libc connect: Connection refused (in socks5_connect() at socks5.c:202)
1634484881 PERROR torsocks[14193]: socks5 libc connect: Connection refused (in socks5_connect() at socks5.c:202)
1634484883 PERROR torsocks[14193]: socks5 libc connect: Connection refused (in socks5_connect() at socks5.c:202)
1634484884 PERROR torsocks[14193]: socks5 libc connect: Connection refused (in socks5_connect() at socks5.c:202)
1634484885 PERROR torsocks[14193]: socks5 libc connect: Connection refused (in socks5_connect() at socks5.c:202)
1634484886 PERROR torsocks[14193]: socks5 libc connect: Connection refused (in socks5_connect() at socks5.c:202)
1634484887 PERROR torsocks[14193]: socks5 libc connect: Connection refused (in socks5_connect() at socks5.c:202)
1634484888 PERROR torsocks[14193]: socks5 libc connect: Connection refused (in socks5_connect() at socks5.c:202)
1634484889 PERROR torsocks[14193]: socks5 libc connect: Connection refused (in socks5_connect() at socks5.c:202)
1634484890 PERROR torsocks[14193]: socks5 libc connect: Connection refused (in socks5_connect() at socks5.c:202)
```

I'm not sure if this process is running correctly as I have left it running for ~20+ hours and still nothing.

I am also having issues connecting to public nodes that I know to be working as I have tested the connection on a Windows drive over the same network.

Any help would be much appreciated.

Edit:

Seems as though the SOCKS5 proxy does not allow traffic unless it is coming through the Tor Browser. Any ideas on a fix?

Comment: Have you followed the [docs](https://github.com/monero-project/monero#using-tor)? And specifically, have you set `TORSOCKS_ALLOW_INBOUND=1` ?

Comment: I have followed the docs and tried that. I think the issue is that I can’t use Tor for anything outside of the Browser. I have confirmed that Tor is running on both 9050 and 9150 yet still get an error. Please see https://tor.stackexchange.com/questions/22819/tor-socks5-not-working-with-anything-other-than-tor-browser for more details on this issue.